# How does MIN function work internally in sql?

Tags: php, sql, aggregate-functions

I wanted to know how does MIN actually function? Using MIN in sql is faster or fetching all the rows from MYSQL db and processing it using php would be faster?

Comment: It depends I guess, does the column have an index? How many records? In what context will MIN be used?

Comment: Internally? Which dbms?

Comment: fetching all the rows will never be faster.

Answer (score 2):

It is **always** faster inside the database:

- **In the optimal case**, the database can use an index on the field, and then it can find the minimum with a very few disc accesses.
- **In the worst case**, the database needs to scan the whole table, but that is still faster than sending all records over the net and then again processing them in a separate client.

Answer (score 0):

Will be faster to process inside the Database in any case. How it will be processed internaly depends on DBMS, indexes and so on.